# How can i transfer a set of files/folder from a linux server to another via script?

Tags: php, web-services, ftp, ssh

I'm creating a php script to backup my website everyday, backup goes to another linux server of mine but how can i compress all files and send to another linux server via a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution (in bash).

```
BACKUP_SERVER_PATH=remote_user@remote_server:/remote/backup/path/
SITE_ROOT=/path/to/your/site/

cd "$SITE_ROOT"
now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
tar -cvzf /tmp/yoursite.$now.tar.gz .
scp /tmp/yoursite.$now.tar.gz "$BACKUP_SERVER_PATH"
```

Some extra stuff to take into account for permission (read access to docroot) and ssh access to the remote server (for scp).

Note that there are really many ways to do this. Another one, if you don't mind storing an uncompressed version of your site is to use rsync.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Timothée Groleau should work, but I prefer doing it the other way around: from my backups machine (a server with a lot of storage available) launch a process to backup all other servers.

In my environment, I use a configuration file that lists all servers, valid user for each server and the path to backup:

*/usr/local/etc/backupservers.conf*

```
192.168.44.34 userfoo /var/www/foosites
192.168.44.35 userbar /var/www/barsites
```

*/usr/local/sbin/backupservers*

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFFILE=/usr/local/etc/backupservers.conf
SSH=`which ssh`

if [ ! -r "$CONFFILE" ]
then
  echo "$CONFFILE not readable" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -w "/var/backups" ]
then
  echo "/var/backups is not writable" >&2
  exit 1
fi

while read host user path
do
  file="/var/backups/`date +%Y-%m-%d`.$host.$user.tar.bz2"
  touch $file
  chmod 600 $file
  ssh $user@$host tar jc $path > $file
done
```

For this to work correctly and without need to enter passwords for every server to backup you need to exchange SSH keys (there are lots of questions/answers on stackoverflow on how to do this).

And last step would be to add this to cron to launch the process each night:

*/etc/crontab*

```
0 2 * * * backupuser /usr/local/sbin/backupservers
```